# how to align legends vertically in google charts api for Column charts?

Tags: google-visualization

i am using google charts api for developing graphs in my application, everything is fine i am able to generate graphs.I am working with column charts the legends are coming horizontally on the graphs.i have 20 columns in the column chart so legends are ovelapping on each other. How can i align them vertically.
Please help me in this regard.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.211.30.24/assetinv/js/jsapi.js"></script>   
 <script type="text/javascript">     
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); 

 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  

<?php

    /* Your Database Name */
    $dbname = 'finalCMS';

    /* Your Database User Name and Passowrd */
    $username = 'assetuser';
    $password = 'password1!';

    try {
      /* Establish the database connection */
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      /* select all the weekly tasks from the table googlechart */
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `EquipmentMainCatagory`,count(`EquipmentMainCatagory`) as CountofAssets from asset a join assetinfo ai on a.assetid=ai.assetid and upper(ai.EquipmentStatus) like upper('%Active%') group by EquipmentMainCatagory");

      $rows = array();
      $table = array();
      $table['cols'] = array(

        // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
        /* 
            note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format 
            as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage 
            and string will be used for Slice title
        */


        array('label' => 'EquipmentMainCatagory', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'CountofAssets', 'type' => 'number')

    );
        /* Extract the information from $result */
        foreach($result as $r) {

          $temp = array();

          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart


          // Values of each slice
          $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['EquipmentMainCatagory']);
          $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['CountofAssets']); 
          $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
        }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    // convert data into JSON format
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    //mysql_close($conn);

     $conn=null;

    ?>







    function drawChart() 
     {   

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable?>);

       //data.setColumns([0, 1,
    //                       { calc: "stringify",
    //                         sourceColumn: 1,
    //                         type: "string",
    //                         role: "annotation" }
    //                       ]);
          var options = {
               title: 'Overall Equipment Categorization Statistics',

              width: 1000,
             height: 500,
              colors: ['#6495ED','#00FF00'],
              vAxis: {title: '# of Assets',titleTextStyle:{bold : true,italic:false}},
              hAxis: {title: 'EquipmentMainCategory', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
        //hAxis: {title: "Month"},


              series: {5: {type: "line"}
              }

            };


        //options.chd=t:data;
        //options.chds=a;

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          // Do not forget to check your div ID

                var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3dmo1'));





         chart1.draw(data, options);


     }
     </script> 



      <div id="piechart_3dmo1" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; position: relative;left: 221px;"></div> 
      'function drawChart() 
 {   

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({"cols":[{"label":"EquipmentMainCatagory","type":"string"},{"label":"count(`EquipmentMainCatagory`)","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"Applications"},{"v":47}]},{"c":[{"v":"Backup Server"},{"v":11}]},{"c":[{"v":"Basic Infra (AD, SCCM, NAV,etc...)"},{"v":48}]},{"c":[{"v":"BMS, PBX and Others"},{"v":7}]},{"c":[{"v":"Database"},{"v":16}]},{"c":[{"v":"DMZ (External)"},{"v":13}]},{"c":[{"v":"EIS Applications"},{"v":7}]},{"c":[{"v":"File and Print"},{"v":27}]},{"c":[{"v":"Mail and Messaging"},{"v":17}]},{"c":[{"v":"Non Server"},{"v":8}]},{"c":[{"v":"SAP or ERP"},{"v":26}]},{"c":[{"v":"Storage"},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"VM Host"},{"v":1}]}]});

   //data.setColumns([0, 1,
//                       { calc: "stringify",
//                         sourceColumn: 1,
//                         type: "string",
//                         role: "annotation" }
//                       ]);
      var options = {
           title: 'Equipment Categorization Statistics of SEA',

         width: 1000,
         height: 500,
          colors: ['#6495ED','#00FF00'],
          vAxis: {title: '# of Assets',titleTextStyle:{bold : true,italic:false}},
          hAxis: {title: 'EquipmentMainCategory', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},


          series: {5: {type: "line"}
          }

        };


    //options.chd=t:data;
    //options.chds=a;

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID

            var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3dmsea'));





     chart1.draw(data, options);


 }
 </script> 



  <div id="piechart_3dmsea" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; position: relative;left: 221px;"></div> 



</div>
'
```

Comment: Do you have some code you can share that we can take a look at?

Comment: i have posted my code here Jeremy Faller.Here in this graph i am getting around 15 columns

Comment: Can you show us the post-rendered javascript (open the page in a browser, view the source, and post the javascript)?  We need to be able to replicate the problem you are seeing in order to find a solution.

Comment: i have posted my code as you told asgallant. Kindly suggest me in this regard.

Comment: Copy/pasta your code seems to work for me. The chart's displaying all the labels at an angle (with some truncation because the labels are long). What behavior is unexpected here?